# Create a Linux packet splitter

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, network-traffic, high-traffic

I am looking for some hints to build a network packet splitter. What i want is some sort of tools/code that **split the packets of a logic link** (tcp/ip connection for ex.) over several network interfaces.

I used with success the Linux bonding driver, however the best performance is only achieved when the bandwidth/latency of the several network interfaces is similar, since the bonding driver uses round robin packet splitting.

Anyone know any tool that can effectively **split packets** (not logical links) over network interfaces using a **weighted manner**, instead of round robin manner?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sysfs to change your bonding mode to a more effective choice for your setup.
`/sys/class/net/bond0/bonding/mode`

You may have some luck also changing the `queue_id` in the same place to make different adapters more important.

Take a look at the [Linux bonding documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt) for information about the settings.